# Unity3D: How to access List<T> elements from ParseObject subclass

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, ilist

I cannot seem to access an array of custom objects (that is a column in a Parse table) after querying for it and receiving the results.

I have a simple custom class call "TextEntry" that contains 2 strings.

```
public class TextEntry
{
    public string key;
    public string text;

    public TextEntry() { }
}
```

I have a ParseObject subclass called "LocalePO", which has an IList member in addition to other native types.

```
[ParseClassName("LocalePO")]
public class LocalePO : ParseObject 
{
    [ParseFieldName("version")]
    public int version
    {
        get { return GetProperty<int>("version"); }
        set { SetProperty<int>(value, "version"); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("code")]
    public string code
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>("code"); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value, "code"); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("name")]
    public string name
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>("name"); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value, "name"); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("keypair")]
    public IList<object> keypair
    {
        get { return GetProperty<IList<object>>("keypair"); }
        set { SetProperty<IList<object>>(value, "keypair"); }
    }


    public LocalePO() { }
}
```

I can query to Parse and successfully return a LocalePO object, but I cannot access the specific "TextEntry" members of the "keypair" List afterwards.

```
        var cloudQuery = new ParseQuery<LocalePO>();
        var queryTask = cloudQuery.FirstAsync();

        // wait for query to return
        while (!queryTask.IsCompleted) yield return null;

        LocalePO locale = queryTask.Result;

        int CloudVersion = locale.version;   // this works

        List<TextEntry> list = new List<TextEntry>(); 

        list = locale.keypair.Cast<TextEntry>.ToList(); // this doesn't work

        foreach (var item in locale.keypair)            
        {

            var entry = item as TextEntry;    // this does not work

            TextEntry entry = (TextEntry)item; // this doesn't work either

            // this is my current solution which works but seems terrible
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
            TextEntry entry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TextEntry>(json);


            list.Add(entry);
        }
```

I feel like I am overlooking something very simple here, but I just want to convert the data I pull from Parse to local objects so I can use the data throughout the app logic.

It seems to me that Parse prefers the IList of type "object"vs an IList of type "TextEntry" type for the ParseFieldName. For example, Parse always returns null for the field if I have the following:

```
[ParseFieldName("keypair")]
public IList<TextEntry> keypair
{
    get { return GetProperty<IList<TextEntry>>("keypair"); }
    set { SetProperty<IList<TextEntry>>(value, "keypair"); }
}
```

Perhaps I should derive TextEntry from ParseObject too? I'm so confused.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var cloudQuery = new ParseQuery<LocalePO>();
    cloudQuery .Include("keypair");
    var queryTask = cloudQuery.FirstAsync();
```

TextEntry will need to derive from parseObject and you will need to register it as a subclass.

Here is an example of a query I am using which has 2 levels of nested iList's of parseObject subclasses

```
    ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<ProgramDataParse>();
    ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<WorkoutDataParse>();
    ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<ExerciseDataParse>();

var programQuery = new ParseQuery<ProgramDataParse>()
        .OrderByDescending("createdAt").Limit(2)
        .Include("workouts")
        .Include("workouts.exercises");
```